# Domain name classification API

Tags: dns, classification, categorization

I need to categorize domains into different categories that offer the best use of a domain name.
Like categorizing 'gamez.com' as a gaming portal.
Is there any service that offers classification of domain name like [Sedo](http://www.sedo.com/) is doing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the systems that I am aware of manage a list, somewhat by hand.

Using a web-filtering proxies (e.g. WebSense) for inspiration, you could scan for keywords contained in the domain name, or in web content/meta tags at the specified location.  However, there are always items that seem to match more than one category, or no category, and these need deeper analysis.

Eventually you end up building your own fairly complex logic, maintaining a list by hand, or buying a list from someone else.

Comment: Thanks But Maintaining by hand is not possible as number is very huge.

Answer (score 4):

[SimilarWeb API](https://developer.similarweb.com/website_categorization_API) does that.

It's really straight forward and returns a given domain's category from a URL.

Comment: First 200 hits are for free, then you need a subscription.

Answer (score 3):

If these are new domains or not used domains. There isn't any information on the internet yet. You can make use of a mechanical turk, like: https://www.mturk.com/ .

You could post an task with your list and possible categories. The downside is this will cost you money.

If these are domains that are already in use you can use a bookmark service as xmarks or delicious. Retrieve all public bookmarks from that domain and count the number of tags. The most used tags will indicate a category of the domain.

Answer (score 0):

I think https://tools.zvelo.com/ has pretty accurate categorization.

For example gamez.com comes back with Hobbies and Interests as IAB-TIER-1 and Video & Computer Games as IAB-TIER-2.

It also provides information if the domain is brand-safe, is it malicious or illegal content?

Comment: Welcome to SO! It feels like your answer is more suitable as a comment than an actual answer.